# SharePoint modify web.config file via appcmd

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2010, appcmd

I want to modify a setting for a particular website via commandline, but I'm having trouble finding the syntax for the command.

I want to change the following xml section in the file c:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories//web.config.

```
<configuration>...
   <SharePoint>...
     <BlobCache location="x">
```

I know I can modify the file C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.conf via appcmd, but I can't figure out how to modify a particular web site's web.config file. I'm guessing I need to do something like this

```
appcmd set config "<site name>" /section:sharepoint/blobcache /enabled="true" /commit:site
```

But that attempts to modify the file applicationhost.conf.

What would be the syntax to modify the web.config file, or is there another utility that can do a better job than appcmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with SharePoint 2010 I would suggestion using a PowerShell script to do this. [Scripting Guy over on technet.com has a blog post that describes doing exactly this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/14/use-powershell-to-script-changes-to-the-sharepoint-web-config-file.aspx).

His solution has you using the [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx) class to manipulate the web.config for an existing web application.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I've been looking for.